# Can non-intermediate representation code such as C++ run on a process virtual machine?

Tags: jvm, virtual-machine

I am progressing though the nand2tetris architecture course where they specify their own ISA called Hack, their own VM code(similar to the JVM), and finally a high-level object oriented language called Jack.

First, I developed an assembler, now I am creating a VM translator. Of course the book is
attempting to teach about the compilation/assembly process:

Jack -> VM code -> Hack Assembly -> Hack machine Code

The virtual machine is introduced in the book as such:

> The basic idea is as follows: Instead of running on a real platform, the intermediate code is designed to run on a Virtual Machine. The VM is an abstract computer that does not exist for real, but can rather be realized on other computer platforms....
> Specifically, one can formulate a virtual machine whose instructions are the intermediate processing steps into which high-level commands are decomposed.

Some wiki quotes as well:

> Process virtual machines are designed to execute computer programs in a platform-independent environment...Its purpose is to provide a platform-independent programming environment that abstracts away details of the underlying hardware or operating system and allows a program to execute in the same way on any platform...A process VM provides a high-level abstraction – that of a high-level programming language (compared to the low-level ISA abstraction of the system VM)...Process virtual machines arose originally as abstract platforms for an intermediate language used as the intermediate representation of a program by a compiler; early examples date to around 1966.

I understand that the VM machine is not real. It must be realized by some implementation. In this case, using Hack assembly. I have been told this is "emulation".

**Question:**
Can non-intermediate represenation run on a virtual machine?

Or, does the concept of the virtual machine only make sense when referring to intermediate code?

Example:
In my book, they specify the language of the VM.

```
push constant 3
pop argument 4
call functionA 3
```

This runs on their virtual machine.

However, what if this language was actually C++?

Let's assume I have a compiler that compiles straight to machine code(e.g. something that isn't like Clang).

```
int x{5};
int y{x+2};
```

Doesn't high level code run on an abstract machine as well?
This code needs to be implemented for a specific platform just like the VM code I showed above.
If so, is this abstract machine considered a virtual machine?

I suspect that process virtual machines refer specifically to abstract machines that deal with intermediate representations. This is evidenced by the wiki quote: "Process virtual machines arose originally as abstract platforms for an intermediate language". If there is no IR, like when compiling C++ straight to my platform specific ISA, then there is no virtual machine.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The C++ language *is* defined in terms of an abstract machine. Everything else is about the difference (the great span between) possible in theory and feasible in practice. The intermediate code is just an optimization.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "C++ is defined in terms of an abstract machine" do you mean even when C++ is compiled straight into machine code(no IR in between)?

I ask because you mention that "intermediate code is just an optimization." I am talking about when there is no IR. I know many c++ compilers do compile to IR, what about those compilers that no not?

Ultimately, I wish to know if concept of a virtual machine exists if there is NO IR in the compilation process.

Comment: The *specification* describes the behavior of an abstract machine and it doesn’t change, regardless of how you implement it. Besides that, no compiler goes straight from the source code (text file[s]) to the native code. There’s always an intermediate representation. It just doesn’t have to look like pseudo assembly or bytecode. See AST, etc. So if someone wants to implement an interpreter for C++, that interpreter would also not operate on source code, but preprocessed code, even when generated on the fly. Creating a persistent form of preprocessed code, like bytecode, is just an optimization

Comment: That raises more questions in my mind.

My book calls this process a "two-tier translational model".

`Instead of running on a real platform, the intermediate code is designed to run on a Virtual Machine. The VM is an abstract computer that does not exist for real, but can rather be realized on other computer platforms...This two-tier translation model is a rather old idea that goes back to the 1970s. Recently, it made a significant comeback following its adoption by modern languages like Java and C#.`

If C++ uses an IR(and presumably a VM), how does it differ to Java?

Comment: Mainly in having no associated standard (persistent) IR, as its typical use case (generate native code) does not require interoperability on the IR level (though, there are some benefits in having it, so projects like [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) were created). So a C++ compiler’s IR can be considered an implementation detail. In contrast, Java and C# have there primary target IR to which they are normally compiled (which doesn’t preclude other targets, like directly to native, or transforming to other IRs, like done when developing for Android) and the result is kept.